# passing data to simulink file from workspace in matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink

I build a model using simulink file , and i used 3 `from workspace` Block , these Blocks must have a digital data , my question is , how to pass data to the simulink file , from workspace ? i have do the examples that mathwork website give , but the problem is (again) how we pass it to simulink file :

`

```
t = [0:0.2:10];
x = sin(t);
y = 10*sin(t);
wave.time = t;
wave.signals.values = [x,y];
wave.signals.dimensions =2;`
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need x,y,t in simulink then you may use:

1.In the MATLAB Command Window, enter:

```
t = [0:0.2:10]';
x = sin(t);
y = 10*sin(t);
```

The time vector must be a column vector.

2.Add a 'From Workspace' block to your model.

3.Double-click the block to open the block parameters dialog. In the Data field, enter the array `[t,x,y]`